# SQL using lag function

Tags: sql, pyspark, lag

What i want to do is to create a column 'ID_DESLIG' with the following rules:

- when STATE is 'LIGADO' then ID_DESLIG will be the id of the previous STATE is 'DESLIGADO', for the same panel;
- when STATE is 'DESLIGADO' then ID_DESLIG will be the id of the current row;

An example of what i want

[image: example]

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want:

```
select t.*,
       (case when state = 'DESLIGADO' then id
             else max(case when state = 'DESLIGADO' then id end) over (order by id)
        end) as desligado_id
from t;
```

In turn, this can be simplified to:

```
max(case when state = 'DESLIGADO' then id end) over (order by id)
```

You could phrase this using `lag()` but only if you know that the states are always interleaved.

In standard SQL (and some databases), this could also be expressed as:

```
max(id) filter (where state = 'DESLIGADO') over (order by id)
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for the help. I tried it and it only puts information on the rows where the state is 'Desligado'. It should put where state = 'Ligado' aswell

Comment: @Shabbir . . . All of these should work on all rows.

Comment: My mistake is that I should use 'LIKE' instead of '='. Thanks again!