# SQL looking to past events

Tags: sql, pyspark

I have a table with events that have a state and an ID. What I want to do is to create a third column that meets this rules:

- If the state is 'LIGADO', then new_column = id
- If the state is NOT 'Ligado', then new_column = id of the previous row that state is 'Ligado'

Here is an image to explain better what i'm trying to do.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JntLM.png)

Comment: How is this different from your previous question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63564578/sql-using-lag-function?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is basically the same as your previous question, with the constant values changed:

```
select t.*,
       (case when state = 'LIGADO' then id
             else max(case when state = 'LIGADO' then id end) over (order by id)
        end) as desligado_id
from t;
```